# Need critics : store objects inside arrays

Tags: java, performance, memory

In order to improve performance of my java applications, i was thinking about making a class with static final fields that describe an object, and then put static methods that retrieves all the data of the object from an array.

example :
let's say i want to create an object person:
let's say a person has an age, height, weight, color of the eyes, and world coordinates.

usually i'd do something like this:

```
  public class Person {
    private int age;
    private int height;
    private int weight;
    private int eyeR;
    private int eyeG;
    private int eyeB;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;
    //... getters and setters
  }
```

I want to send the persons from a client to a server, so i have to serialize the objects and send them to the server wich will deserialize the object and resurrect the person on the other side, now we all know that java objects are stored in the heap and that every object have a minimum of bytes that are allocated to describe the object.

What I wanna do is this instead :
make a a class that describes an object  person :

```
public class Person {
 // size contains the number of bytes to describe my person
 public static final int size; 
 //this byte here is used to identify a Person in a float array
 public static byte classID = 0;
 //these variables contains the position of my attributes inside a float array
 // since floats / int are all coded in 4 bytes
 public static final int age = 0;
 public static final int height = 1;
 public static final int eyeR = 2; 
 public static final int eyeG = 3;
 public static final int eyeB = 4;
 public static final int x = 5;
 public static final int y = 6;
 public static final int z = 7;

 //i don't check for nullity, i trust myself.
 public static int getAge(final float[] person) {
    return person[Person.age]; 
 }
 public static void setAge(final float[] person, float age) {
    return person[Person.age] = age; 
 }

 ... do the same thing for the rest also you can store
```

}

I'd really like to know if this solution is viable, because since i am using only float arrays to store my person data, i can get spatial proximity of my data in the memory, so i guess if I access the data i wont make any page misses.

also i wont have to serialize or deserialize my objects, because my float array is good as is, i'll just use my static methods to access my float array.

Comment: Viable? Yes. Advisable? No.

Comment: An important thing to change in ones mindset when switching from C to Java is to just *stop caring that much about low level stuff*.

Comment: *"In order to improve performance of my java applications"* Did you run this application though a profiler to identify this as your performance issue?

Comment: Also note that the code you've given won't even compile - there's no implicit conversion from `float` to `int`.

Comment: Jon, i'm just considering that my floats are ints, when i'll need to display them ,'ll remove the .0000

Comment: @user2207996: You've missed my points: 1) By storing `int` values as `float` values, you're limiting the set of values you can represent; 2) Your sample code is invalid. Why not post *valid* code?

Answer (score 4):

> now we all know that java objects are stored in the heap and that every object have a minimum of bytes that are allocated to describe the object.

Yup, and this applies to arrays too.

I can't see your code saving significant amounts of memory, but it'll make the code significantly harder to read and maintain, in my view.

Really, just don't do this.

> because since i am using only float arrays to store my person data, i can get spatial proximity of my data in the memory, so i guess if I access the data i wont make any page misses.

With all the data in a `Person` instance you'll have spatial proximity too. This is another non-benefit.

Comment: I know but i can be sure that the data of the person is stored next to each other in the memory.

Comment: @user2207996: I've never known a JVM to *not* do that. These are primitive values, don't forget. Do you even have any evidence that you have a problem to resolve? Do you understand that this will make your code harder to work with?

Comment: with this, i dont have to deserialize my object after i send it from a client

Comment: @user2207996: So you save one small piece of code for serializing and deserializing (or using a library) at the expense of readability *everywhere*. It seems that your heart is set on this though... Oh, and note that not every `int` can be exactly represented as a `float`, so you'll potentially lose data there, too. Probably not an issue with the values you're likely to use, but far from elegant.

Comment: also, I can make one huge float to store collection of persons, and be able to iterate over it, and be sure to not make page faults? i've been coding java for a while i'm not an expert but would love to have an opinion on the performances of this, when used with millions of instances

Comment: @user2207996: My opinion is that *as ever*, you should focus on readability first. Yes, if you have one huge array instead of lots of instances that would save some memory - but at the cost of even *more* readability. (You'd need to remember an index into the array for each person.) I think I've made my opinion pretty clear now: this is a *bad* idea, and I *strongly* advise you not to take it any further.

Comment: thanks jon, I'll do some tests on my own to see how well this performs, i'm not saying i'll use it, but I had this in mind, for a moment and just thought this could be usefull in cases where you have to manipulate millions of objects

Comment: also instead of using indexes of the objects in the array, i could also use a kind of trustable hashtable, using a float array also.

Comment: @user2207996: I have no idea what you mean by a "trustable hashtable" but it sounds like you're making things even *more* complicated. Before you test how the complicated solution performs, why don't you test how the *simple* solution (the one that goes along with the way Java was designed to be used) performs, and compare that against your concrete performance goals. If you haven't *got* concrete performance goals yet, now is a good time to set them.

Comment: what i mean by trustable, is a kind of hashtable table that ignores collisions, since HashMaps in hava calculates the hashcode 2 times, it calculates the hashkey of the object and then rehashes the key to minimise the collisions, i was thinking about ignoring the problem of collisions, and just do stuff around it by either storing the data in another hashmap, or things like that, i didn't implement this, for the moment i'm just supposing things.

I just wanted to share thoughts with you guys, no harms meant.

Comment: @user2207996: You seem to be assuming one specific kind of hash table. What's the point of calculating the hash code twice, given that it should be the same both times? Yes, you use it to bucket and then *also* keep the original hash code, but then you need to check the key for equality anyway. Again, you seem to be in favour of doing an awful lot of work for a performance benefit which *at best* you haven't proved necessary... (It's not even clear how you'd use the hash table...)

Comment: i'll try to make an implementation and use profiler to see how it does :p, oh and don''t worry i'm not using this at work, i keep my code always readable and clean and always use sonar when i code, i'm just experimenting things here.

Comment: @user2207996: There's no point in *only* implementing the complicated solution. You should implement the *simple* solution first, and benchmark that. Do you know what your actual requirements are? Without those, it's pointless.

Comment: yes, i'd like to transfer millions of persons over Tcp, and then calculate a new position for every person and then resend to client, using nio.

i'll implement both ways and see how they perform.

Comment: anyways thanks again Jon for the discussion